# Using an API to generate virtual numbers

Tags: django, api

I will build a website of virtual numbers, where the user can buy a number for a certain period of time and, after registering on a platform that requires a number to send a code, my website will receive the code through a webhook and return to the user.
The central question is: which service fits my need?
I thank.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is but django REST framework wil fit your needs.